Cannot use command substitution inside Git Bash on Windows: "bash: command substitution: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `)'"
In a Bash terminal on Linux, this works fine:
# define some bash func
foo() {
    echo "foo"
}

# Back up your system's default PS1 prompt 1 string, which controls the prompt
# output
if [ -z "$PS1_BAK" ]; then
    PS1_BAK="$PS1"
fi

# Set the PS1 prompt 1 string to run the `foo` function every time the 
# prompt is printed
PS1='$(foo)'"\n$PS1_BAK"

Now, every time I press Enter, it prints foo above my command prompt, as expected. Example:
foo
gabriel@my_computer:~$ 
foo
gabriel@my_computer:~$ 
foo
gabriel@my_computer:~$ 

I want the same behavior on Windows in the Git Bash terminal which comes with Git for Windows. This trick is how I make my terminal automatically tell me the git branch, hash, and tag whenever I am inside a git repo. (See where I set my PS1 string via PS1= here).
However, in Git Bash on Windows, the above code produces this error instead:
bash: command substitution: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
bash: command substitution: line 1: `foo)'

Why? And more importantly: how do I make it work in Git Bash on Windows?
Note that the Git Bash terminal is based on MSYS2, if that helps.
Update:
Replace the definition of foo above with:
foo() {
    echo "$(pwd)"
}

...to print the present working directory, and you get the same behavior still: Linux works, Git Bash does not. Git Bash has problems with command substitution in the prompt strings.

This appears to be a known issue upstream

The already-existing PS1 prompt string uses backtick-style command substitution, so that is what we have to use. Here is the default PS1 variable provided in Git Bash on Windows, as shown by echo "$PS1":
'\[\033]0;$TITLEPREFIX:$PWD\007\]\n\[\033[32m\]\u@\h \[\033[35m\]$MSYSTEM \[\033[33m\]\w\[\033[36m\]`__git_ps1`\[\033[0m\]\n$'

Notice this part: `__git_ps1`. The __git_ps1 part is a Bash function they provide, so wrapping it in backticks makes it do command substitution.
So, the solution for use in Git Bash on Windows is to use backtick-style command substitution instead. For my case, it would look like this:
PS1='`foo`'"\n$PS1_BAK"

Now it works fine in both Linux and in Git Bash on Windows.
@thatotherguy also pointed out to me in this comment that there's an existing bug report about this in MSYS2.
See here: MSYS2: bash: '\n' after command substitution in $PS1 causes error #1839.
Trial and error tells me that only the older style `` instead of $() works in the PS1 prompt string in Git bash.
I also left a comment about this here: Backticks vs braces in Bash:

In Git Bash they are not always equivalent. Inside the PS1 prompt string, active command substitution must use backticks!: `command` vs $(command). See my answer here: Cannot use command substitution inside Git Bash on Windows: "bash: command substitution: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `)'"

References

Though this answer is entirely written by me, I did have a chat with an AI to prompt me to try the `command` command substitution style instead of the $(command) style.
I prompted GitHub Copilot with this:

difference in command substitution with $() vs backticks.

And it gave me some information which prompted me to try backtick-style command substitution instead.
I cannot say whether or not `command` is generally more portable, but clearly it works in Git Bash on Windows where $(command) does not.


See also

PS1 command substitution fails when containing newlines on msys bash
Bug report: MSYS2: bash: '\n' after command substitution in $PS1 causes error #1839


@thatotherguy, this answer is not generated by AI, but that small bit I quote is. Let me reformat the answer to make this more obvious. I don't think my answer violates the policy since it is not AI-generated. I wrote it. Update: Done. Answer reworded.

@thatotherguy, quote removed.

You can keep $(...) notation with :
PS1=$'$(foo)\n'"$PS1_BAK"



3.1.2.4 ANSI-C Quoting
  Character sequences of the form $’string’ are treated as a special
  kind of single quotes. The sequence expands to string, with 
  backslash-escaped characters in string replaced as specified by the 
  ANSI C standard. Backslash escape sequences, if present, are decoded 
  as follows:



Indeed, that does work! Can you explain how and why?

What does that extra $ do out front?

The way you put \n seems to cause problem. I used ANSI-C Quoting with \n inside it.

I see in the default PS1 variable in Git Bash on Windows, they use the backtick-style command substitution instead. I've updated my answer with this information.
